# how do I save multiple items under one table in firebase

Tags: cordova, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

this is my .ts file. When I save an item, it replaces the previous. I want it to have multiple items in an increasing order.

```
     export class PostSermonPage {

     sermon = {} as Sermon;

     constructor( private afauth: AngularFireAuth, 
             private afDatabase:AngularFireDatabase,
             public navCtrl: NavController, 
             public navParams: NavParams) {}

          createsermon(){
                  this.afauth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {
                 this.afDatabase.object(`sermon/${auth.uid}`).set(this.sermon)
                .then(()=>this.navCtrl.push('SermonPage'));

                 });

               }

           }
```

how do i save more items in a table in firebase?

Comment: When you say 'in an increasing order', are you after auto incrementing your posts' unique IDs as they are saved in the DB?

Comment: yes. I mean each item saved using a unique id and not being replaced by the recent content.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `set` on a location in the database, it replaces any existing value at that location.

If you want to add a new value under the same location, use `push` to generate a new unique child under the location. So:

```
this.afDatabase.list(`sermon/${auth.uid}`).push(this.sermon)
.then(()=>this.navCtrl.push('SermonPage'));
```

This will generate a unique location under `sermon/${auth.uid}` with the contents of `this.sermon`.

Comment: Thank you @Frank Van Puffelen.  Your code is correct apart from that instead of `.object` we need to use `list`. Your answer helped me to find the write code for my use. `this.afDatabase.list(`sermon`).push(this.sermon)
        .then(()=>this.navCtrl.push('SermonPage'));`

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution. Firstly

```
 this.afDatabase.object(`sermon/${auth.uid}`).set(this.sermon)
```

Should not have been `object` then `set` but `list` then `push` like this:

```
   this.afDatabase.list(`sermon`).push(this.sermon)
```

Then (`sermon/${auth.uid}`) will create a unique Id under sermon and all other objects with their unique Id will be saved under the first Unique Id.

To have all objects saved under sermon table with their unique Id, I used the following code.

```
    createsermon(){
        this.afauth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {
        this.afDatabase.list(`sermon`).push(this.sermon)
        .then(()=>this.navCtrl.push('SermonPage'));
      });
    }
```